# SQL Statement deleting entire table

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-delete, bulk

I have two tables that both have an ID number which are linked together (`AllUsers` and `AllProfiles`). When the user presses a button, I want  the `AllUsers` table to check for IDs it has that are not present in the `AllProfiles` table and delete them. I'm new to SQLCE and hacked this together. The problem is, it keeps deleting the entire table. Why?

```
DELETE FROM AllUsers
WHERE  EXISTS
    (SELECT       ID
     FROM         AllUsers
     WHERE        (ID NOT IN
                     (SELECT ID
                        FROM AllProfiles)))
```

Also, is this an efficient way of bulk deleting thousands of records? I tried Linq's DeleteAllOnSubmit but it was too slow. I'm hoping since the above is comparing two tables directly, it should be efficient.
(I don't want to use cascading as I need control of each table individually)

EDIT - The `SELECT` statement correctly returns the missing IDs, so there's something wrong with the `DELETE FROM AllUsers WHERE EXISTS` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically saying

```
delete from allusers
where TRUE -- this is pseudo, but you get the idea
```

Your original query deletes the whole table because the only condition is boolean... if that returns data then it'll delete all the data.  If your `exists` clause does not return data it would not delete any data.

You want something like this (I'm not fluent with CE, but you should be able to make a minor modification if it doesn't 100% transport over to CE):

```
delete from allusers
where id not in
(
    select id
    from allprofiles
)
```

Comment: I hate using IN.  Can SQL-CE use EXISTS?

Comment: @Dems Why do you hate `IN`??! :)  As for SQL CE, I can't really say either way.  I'd be lying if I said I was a SQL CE expert (or even mildly verse in it).

Comment: It's often less well optimised than alternatives.  And is overly used by people who can't JOIN.  And makes people try `IN (@comma_delimited_string_of_chaff)`.  And is sometimes limited to a maximum sized data-set.  And it just isn't perrrrrrrty.